# duplicates within a 30 day period in samples from location A

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset with 3 variables: `test_date`, `unique_ID`, and `location`, which provides location of testing and can be either `"department"` or `"practice"`.

I want to exclude data from my dataset if the unique ID is present for more than one occasion within a 30 day period. Also the location must be `"practice"`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Thomas Rosengren! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Also, please make an earnest effort at the solution and ask about a specific issue with your attempt. If needed, [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) before asking. Happy coding!

Comment: "Location must be practice": `subset(x, location == "practice")`. "Within 30 days" sounds like a sliding window, look up `zoo::rollapply`, `data.table::frollapply`, or the `slider` package. "More than one occasion" sounds like `length(unique(location)) > 1` within each window. Good luck!